# opencsv not writing to a file

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using opencsv 3.0 version. For some reason it is not writing out the records to the CSV file. It worked fine with version 2.3. However, I wanted to use the CSVIterator class. Any help is appreciated.

```
 public void writeGradesIntoFile(GradeReport gradeReport,String outputFileName)
    {
            File outputCSVFile = null;
            CSVWriter csvFileWriter = null;
            String[] lastRecord = null;
            try {
                outputCSVFile = new File(outputFileName + ".csv");
                csvFileWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputCSVFile, true),
                        ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
                if (checkFileExistsAndEmpty(outputCSVFile)) {
                    String[] firstRecord = new String[] { gradeReport.getEmpId(),
                            Integer.toString(gradeReport.getScore()) };
                    csvFileWriter.writeNext(firstRecord);
                }
             } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                  ioEx.printStackTrace();                           
        }
}
```

Here is the pom entry

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to close the writer by calling `csvFileWriter.close()` - ideally this should be done in a `finally` block.